# How do I make a variable made out of a string global in python?

Tags: python, blackjack

I'm trying to make a blackjack game.
I've made functions for drawing cards and checking if sum in one's hand exceeds 21 but only for 3 players. That was easy I had 3 lists.

But I want to do it for N number of players so I want to keep my functions and make another one that switches between players and their hands.

```
def create_hands():
global total_players
for x in range(1, total_players+1):
    vars()["hand_%d" % x] = []
    print hand_1
```

I want to create as many hands as in hand_1, hand_2, etc... for as many N players (total_players)

Because of the code above i get an *global name 'hand_1' is not defined* error

So it all comes down to:

1. How do I make *"hand_%d" % x* global ?
2. Is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better way. Simply create a list of lists. Playing with vars should be ommited, if possible. It's really hard to read and debug and you will regret that attitude lately. When you create a list like `players -> hand -> cards`, or even a dict of players like `players['player1'][3]` for player's one third card, you will be much more happy with that.

Comment: Well, you're in python, and python, beneath of a language stands for a type of thinking. You can define a `players = {'player1': [1, 2, 3], 'players2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}` with no problem. Just google for "python structures" and read a little about it. Everything is an object, so take advance from it.

Comment: You could also try actually using objects. I've seen someone trying to implement a blackjack game recently without using a single class - it usually ends up being a procedural hell of which you can't make sense. I think you sould seriously consider implementing classes such as card, hand and deck. You can then use a list (or a dict) when you store hands (or players & their hand).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that vars() is an alias for locals(), which has the following comment in the official documentation:

```
Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; 
changes may not affect the values of local and free variables 
used by the interpreter.
```

In other words, adding keys to vars() does **NOT** necessarily update the local var iables table (which is why you're getting the `global name hand_1 is not defined` error - `vars()[ "hand_1" ]` doesn't make `hand_1` into a local variable).

As Gandi mentioned, there are far easier ways to do what you are trying to do - use a list of lists or something similar. There are far more conventional ways to solve this problem than creating arbitrarily-named local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it *is* possible to do that.  Replace

```
vars()["hand_%d" % x] = []
```

with

```
globals()["hand_%d" % x] = []
```

Be warned however that this solution is kinda hackish and can easily lead to problems (difficulty in maintenance, losing track of the spontaneously created variables, etc.)